# PowerShell Replace with Wildcard

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace, wildcard

I've done a little digging in several areas and have been bashing my head on my desk over this for a couple of hours and am starting to think that I'm over-thinking it. Here's hoping that it's a really simple answer.

Ultimately, all I need to do is replace "(*)" in a string with "" but I can't figure out how to do this. I've read a bunch of stuff about regex and it's just not making sense.

Example of what I want to do

```
#create a test string
$string = "test 001 (testing 123)"
#replace everything in () with ""
$string.Replace("(*)","")
```

result: $string equals "test 001 "

I suspect this is child's play to someone out there so I'm hoping someone comes across this and is able to answer it really quick. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After all that, I got it to work like this. Don't know if it's kosher but it should get the job done.

`[regex]::replace($temp,'\(.*\)', '')`

Answer (score 1):

Since the parenthesis are regex meta charcaters, you need to escape it in-order to match the literal parenthesis.

```
\([^)]*\)
```

Use the above regex and then replace the match with an empty string. Escape the backslash one more time if necessary.

`[^)]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `)`, zero or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pW3cT7/1)

Comment: It took me a minute of reading and rereading your solution to figure out what exactly you were doing. I ended up doing it with .* because I won't have any situation where I have parenthesis inside of parenthesis. Thanks for responding. 

I have a new and improved issue which is specific to PowerShell and you might know how to answer it. How can I do a replace with wildcards where I ignore the wildcard characters?

For example, I want to replace (2015) with [2015] but want it to apply to any date with the pattern (20%%). I know how to match the pattern, I'm doing it with \(20..\). However (1/2)

Comment: When I try to perform a replace, I have issues not replacing the wildcards. Any idea how to apply a mask to the replacement string? This is what I came up with, which doesn't work
`[regex]::replace($test,'\(20..\)', '[20..]')`

Comment: Or, if we could exlude these patterns from the previous:
(20..) & (of ..)

Comment: regex `\((20..)\)`, replacement string `[$1]` . you could use `\1` instead of `$1` also.

Comment: I ended up doing this with some crafty if/then/while magic. Good enough to get the job done. Thanks for helping me out earlier.